# Session null, what does it means?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

Whenever in a filter/servlet, we retrieve the session with `request.getSession( false )`, what does it means ?

I know that when session is null, it can either represent any of these two cases.

1. There is no JSESSION Id cookie associated with the request, request is fresh request.
2. The session associated with JSESSION id has expired ?

I am using Spring-Security in my application. I have created a filter that intercepts all requests, checks if there a session and an authentication object associated with the request, if there isn't I assume that the request is a fresh, and I create a new session and create a blank authentication object with `NULL` principal and blank authorities list, and set authenticated to true.

```
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession( false );
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if( session == null && auth == null ) {
        LOGGER.debug( "In AuthenticationFilter | In doFilter | Session and Authentication are both null.");
        session = httpRequest.getSession( true );

        auth = CookieAuthentication.createBlankAuthentication();
        auth.setAuthenticated( true );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( auth );

        chain.doFilter(req,  res );
    }
    else if( session == null && auth != null ) {
        LOGGER.debug( "In AuthenticationFilter | In doFilter | Session is null but authentication is not.");
        LOGGER.info( "In AuthenticationFilter | Returning Response.");

        Response response = new Response();

        response = new Response();
        response.setMessage( "Session Has Expired.");
        response.setFlag( "SE" );

        httpResponse.setStatus( 401 );

        try {
            httpResponse.getWriter().write( response.toJSON() );
            httpResponse.getWriter().flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {             
            LOGGER.error( e.getMessage() );
        }
    } else if ( session != null && auth != null ) {
        LOGGER.debug( "In AuthenticatorFilter | In doFilter | Session and Authentication are not null. ");          
        chain.doFilter( req,  res );
    } else {

        /**
         * Some Fatal error.
         * We shouldn't be here.
         */

        Response response = new Response();

        response = new Response();
        response.setMessage( "Un Authenticated");
        response.setFlag( "UA" );

        httpResponse.setStatus( 401 );

        try {
            httpResponse.getWriter().write( response.toJSON() );
            httpResponse.getWriter().flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {             
            LOGGER.error( e.getMessage() );
        }

    }
```

What are the various cases when I can receive session null and authentication object null and not null.

What I have assumed is as follows.

```
Session : null, authenticatin : null -> Fresh Request.
Session : null, authentication : not-null -> Expired Session.
Session : not-null, authentication : null -> Shouldn't happen normally.
Session : not-null, authentication : not-null -> Previously authenticated request.
```

Please let me know about my misunderstanding of the concept.
And other that these, I want to know how can I differentiate that a session doesn't exist and has expired when I receive session as null.

Answer (score 0):

`getSession(false)` means get session, but if there is no session, do not make one.